# symfony with doctrine using subclass for view - doctrine generates invalid sql

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I asked a similar question, but this is a refined version in an attempt to isolate the issue.

Using symfony 3 I'm following this procedure to create a subclass of a table in order to represent a view.  Please note I've kept this contrived example as simple as possible...

init db :

```
create database crm;
use crm;
create table customer(customer_id int primary key auto_increment, companyname text);
create view customer_view as select * from customer;
```

create a new symfony project :

```
symfony new crm
```

edit parameters.yml :

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: crm
```

reverse engineer metadata XML

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
```

create the view mapper manually at `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/CustomerView.orm.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\CustomerView" table="customer_view">
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

generate entities:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

create the subclass entity manually :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class CustomerView extends Customer
{
}
?>
```

Now I create a controller that simply queries the view:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use ...

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $doc = $this->get ( 'doctrine' );
        $repo = $doc->getRepository ( 'AppBundle:CustomerView' );
        $result = $repo->createQueryBuilder ( 'c' )->setMaxResults(25)->getQuery ()->getResult ();

        return new Response('Result: ' . $result);
    }
}
```

and visiting this page I get the following exception:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT c0_.companyname AS companyname_0, c0_.customer_id AS customer_id_1 FROM customer_view c1_ LIMIT 25':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c0_.companyname' in 'field list'
```

As you can see, doctrine has generated a query using an alias `c1` for the view, but using an alias `c0` to select the columns!

Is this a bug in doctrine, or am I doing something it shouldn't support?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurring because Entity class inheritance should not be used this way in Doctrine.  Doctrine considers subclassed Entites to imply db-level inheritance.  Instead of subclassing, each field of `customer` that appears in the `customer_view` should be declared in the CustomerView class